# I got exception array index out of bound in args[0] in line: if ( args[0].equals("t") || args[0].equals("time") ) when i am running below code

Tags: java

I got run time exception `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException` in below code, in line:

`if ( args[0].equals("t") || args[0].equals("time") )`.

Please help me with this.

```
public static void main(String[] args)   {
   System.out.println("Starting Test Cases");
    try
    {
        // Parse the command line args
        int policy = 0;
        if ( args[0].equals("t") || args[0].equals("time") ) {
            policy = ResourceCharacteristics.TIME_SHARED`enter code here`;
        }
        else if ( args[0].equals("s") || args[0].equals("space") ) {
            policy = ResourceCharacteristics.SPACE_SHARED;
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Error -- Invalid allocation policy....");
            return;
        }

        // determine which test case number to choose
        int testNum = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        if (testNum < MIN || testNum > MAX) {
            testNum = MIN;
        }

        ////////////////////////////////////////
        // First step: Initialize the GridSim package. It should be called
        // before creating any entities. We can't run this example without
        // initializing GridSim first. We will get run-time exception
        // error.
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        boolean trace_flag = false;  // true means tracing GridSim events

        // list of files or processing names to be excluded from any
        // statistical measures
        String[] exclude_from_file = { "" };
        String[] exclude_from_processing = { "" };

        // the name of a report file to be written. We don't want to write
        // anything here.
        String report_name = null;

        // initialize all revelant variables
        double baudRate[] = {1000, 5000}; // bandwidth for even, odd
        int peRating[] = {10, 50};   // PE Rating for even, odd
        double price[] = {3.0, 5.0};   // resource for even, odd
        int gridletLength[] = {1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000};

        // Initialize the GridSim package
        int totalUser = 2;    // total Users for this experiment
        GridSim.init(totalUser, calendar, trace_flag, exclude_from_file,
                exclude_from_processing, report_name);

        //////////////////////////////////////
        // Second step: Creates one or more GridResource objects
        int totalResource = 3;  // total GridResources for this experiment
        int totalMachine = 1;   // total Machines for each GridResource
        int totalPE = 3;        // total PEs for each Machine
        createResource(totalResource, totalMachine, totalPE, baudRate,
                       peRating, price, policy);

        /////////////////////////////////////
        // Third step: Creates grid users
        int totalGridlet = 4;     // total Gridlets for each User
        createUser(totalUser, totalGridlet, gridletLength, baudRate,
                   testNum);

        ////////////////////////////////////
        // Fourth step: Starts the simulation
        GridSim.startGridSimulation();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Unwanted errors happen");
        System.out.println( e.getMessage() );
        System.out.println("Usage: java Test [time | space] [1-8]");
    }
    System.out.println("=============== END OF TEST ====================");
}
```

When it's executed, it will throw an exception and catch block executes always.

Comment: you must provide command line argument.

Comment: If so just do check if  your `args` length `>0`

Answer (score 3):

This means your program is invoked without command-line or IDE-emulated arguments, hence your `args` has size `0` and referencing index `0` will throw the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

If you're running this from command line, add a program argument (e.g. `java MyMainClass time`).

If you're running in an IDE, you can add arguments to your run configuration.

In Eclipse:

- Right-click your project
- Select `Run/Debug settings`
- Edit your desired run configuration (typically only one)
- Select the `Arguments` tab
- Add your `program arguments`

**Note**

A good practice is to check the size of any array before referencing any of its elements, e.g. `if (args.length > 0) {...}`

Comment: I am doing execution in eclipse.so how can i fix that issue.

Comment: sir, I am not able to understand that what is the problem in this line if ( args[0].equals("t") || args[0].equals("time") ) {
                policy = ResourceCharacteristics.TIME_SHARED;
            }

Comment: @SophiyaSheikh no need to call me "sir" :) the problem is you're referencing your `args` array, which represents the arguments passed to your program, and specifically its index `0`. But if there's no arguments given at all, there's no index `0`, hence the exception.

Comment: i understand what is the problem now, Please tell me how to correct it.

Comment: @SophiyaSheikh read my answer. You have both ways to add arguments and a way to check for array size.

Answer (score 1):

You first need to check is there is any args *at all*:

```
if (args.length == 0) {
    System.out.println("Error -- Allocation policy not specified.");
    return;
}
// other checks you currently have left as is
```

Comment: You need to pass command line arguments to it. Try this on a command line: `java edu.mycourse.MyClass time` executed in the home directory if you project

Answer (score 0):

I ran my program through IntelliJ IDEA and had to pass arguments into the main method.

You can do that through **Edit Configurations**.

[image: Screenshot for edit configurations]

I followed the instructions [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/5278137/What-arguments-should-I-pass-in-this-program-to-av).

Answer (score -1):

Your program should also handle the negative scenario (so as to not throw index out of bounds exception). Put a check to see the length of input args and should message/log appropriately to indicate that input is required.